# Numpy not installing, also "Can't find a usable init.tcl in the following directories:"

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to start the newcoder.io data vizualization tutorial but am having a difficult time installing numpy on Windows (8.1, python 2.7).

When I go to install it using pip the process never completes, even if I leave it for an hour or more. It doesn't give me any errors or anything either so I don't know how to track down what is causing this.

Here is what is looks like:

```
(datavizproj)PS C:\Users\Ray\github\new-coder\dataviz> pip install numpy
Collecting numpy
  Using cached numpy-1.9.2.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: numpy
  Running setup.py install for numpy
```

Any thoughts on what to do? Should I delete the cached file and have it redownload it? I looked in Python27/lib/site-packages and didn't even see numpy and I thought that is where the file should be kept after pip finds them.

EDIT: I added "Can't find a usable init.tcl in the following
directories:" to the title to help anyone else who has this separate problem find the solution posted below.

Answer (score 1):

Numpy is implemented in C and thus requires a C compiler to install. To circumvent the issue, use a precompiled installer from the Source Forge page [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/numpy/files/NumPy/1.9.2/numpy-1.9.2-win32-superpack-python2.7.exe/download). Then try to import to verify the installation.

```
import numpy # see whether it's been installed
```

Comment: thank you very much! Tried to do this and figured out that the problem was that I had a 64 bit version of Python which apparently doesn't play nice with pip, so I just removed it and put on 32bit.

Comment: You're welcome. Please mark as answer with the check mark beside my solution.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to track down my issue (thanks Malik Brahimi, you led me on the right track to figure this out)

My issue was that I installed the 64bit version of Python, and pip can't install a 64 bit version of numpy because there is no official source.

My solution was to remove python and reinstall a 32 bit version as I don't actually need 64bit and apparently there is better compatibility for modules using 32bit.

I came to another problem later on, where the init.tcl file could not be found when I was running a program that use matplotlib. Python was searching for the init.tcl in python27/bin/tcl8.5 but the correct directory is python27/tcl/tcl8.5 . To fix this I added 2 system variables: TCL_LIBRARY, with the path C:/Python27/tcl/tcl8.5 and TK_LIBRARY, with the path C:/Python27/tcl/tk8.5

Answer (score 0):

you may want to retry using easy_install?

Otherwise, try deleting any cached items.